# How to pass object to RESTful Service with GET request?

Tags: wcf, rest

I have seen some posts in stackoverflow saying "[sending list of items in the GET Method, is NOT allowed. It has to be accomplished via POST method only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119077/input-an-array-in-the-rest-web-service)"

My code looks like

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Employee/{emp}",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Employee GetEmpDetails(string emp);
```

and my input json object will be "{'id':1,'name':'test',....}
Is there any alternative way of achieving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: what makes you think you'll get a different answer?

Comment: I am also trying to pass C# object to my Get method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to send list of items with GET, it's just that out of the box only primitive values are supported. String values work just fine, but if you want to pass a complex object, you need to create a custom `QueryStringConverter`. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/08/09/wcf-extensibility-querystringconverter.aspx explains how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but passing some 10 params through query string looks complex. is there any alternative way of achieving this through GET request ?

Comment: GET requests cannot have a body, so the only way to pass a parameter is via the query string. If you're passing many parameters, you should consider changing it to a POST request instead.

Comment: Thanks Carlos finally i changed to POST request and it worked but it is misleading to user even though service is fetching the results but in REST/help it shows POST request.I guess this is limitation of REST.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your service RESTful you will most probably use HTTP PUT for Add method and HTTP POST for Update method. It is absolutely ok to pass object to these methods because objet will be part of HTTP request's body, not part of URI. URI is important for HTTP GET requests. HTTP GET requests should be only for data retrieval not for data modification.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.In my GET request i am not modifying the data just sending filter criteria( eg: contains some 10 parameters) and just retrieving the result based on filter criteria. how can we achieve this via GET request.

Comment: You can achieve your goal using Servicestack(http://www.servicestack.net/) totally DTO based , please look at that.

Comment: @Arun Rana : That's great! you have any suggestions on how to do this using Java?

Comment: @Wizard sorry i do not know using java

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up HTTP GET/POST/... requests and REST GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/...
When you wanna request something RESTfully - you do a GET request. In your case I think it should look like

```
employee/{id}
```

or

```
employee/{name}
```

Please also note that usage of lowercase in the URI is preferable.
If you need multiple GET criteria, I think it could look like:

```
employee/id/{id}/name/{name}
```

Comment: Thanks, We already saw this option, since we want to send a custom filter containing 10-12 parameters, the url might seem very lengthy - e.g. - employee/name/{name}/age/{age}/address/{address}/doj/{date of join}/dob/{birth date}........... etc, our idea was to pack this into a json object and deserialize at the service, like - {'name':'sam','age':'23'.....}.

Comment: WebGet works with the querystring option as in the url e.g above but fails when we try to send a single string parameter with the json type content. we saw samples where it is done with POST/PUT request, but we want to know if there's any way to do it by simple GET

Comment: If the amount/names of the parameters is unknown ahead, you could change the attribute to
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "employee",RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
and then parse URI parameters "manually" inside the method.

But then, of course, you will need to pass your "search params" object as URI parameter.