# WCF REST GET with JSON request object?

Tags: c#, wcf, json, rest, get

If I define a GET operation as follows:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/findcategories", Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 FindCategoriesResponse FindCategories(FindCategoriesRequest request);
```

but when I try this I get the exception:

```
Operation 'FindCategories' in contract 'IComplaintService' uses GET, but also has body parameter 'request'. GET operations cannot have a body. Either make the parameter 'request' a UriTemplate parameter, or switch from WebGetAttribute to WebInvokeAttribute.
```

Is there no way of accepting a JSON object as a parameter when doing GET request?

Thanks

Comment: Please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336807/how-to-pass-object-to-restful-service-with-get-request/8337050#8337050

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there no way of accepting a JSON object as a parameter when doing GET request?

Nope. With a GET request you use query string parameters. If you want to send an entire JSON object you should use POST.

Comment: Thank you. So, imagine that I want to allow the consumer to use this method and pass a complicated filter as a parameter, which contains for example lists etc. Do you have to make it a POST, even if it's a regular request that doesn't change state?

Comment: @Lud, you could also use multiple query string parameters for each filter and stay with GET.

Comment: @Lud, not limited to string only. Could be int, decimal, float, ... any scalar type.