# Passing an object to WCF Service through GET Request and Response

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I am bit new to WCF services.  In my current, I have develop a hello world Restful WCF service. The following is the code of my RESTful web service.

The RESTful service contract is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace RestfulWCFService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestfulTestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="GET", ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate="xml/{name}")]
        string SayHelloXml(string name);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "json/{name}")]
        string SayHelloJson(string name);
    }
}
```

The interface implementation is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace RestfulWCFService
{

    public class RestfulTestService : IRestfulTestService
    {


        string IRestfulTestService.SayHelloXml(string name)
        {
            return "Hello  " + name;
        }

        string IRestfulTestService.SayHelloJson(string name)
        {
            return "Hello  " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

I have deployed this service on IIS and now I am accessing this web service using the following URL.

http://localhost/RestfulWCFService/RestfulTestService.svc/xml/pankesh

The webservice is returning me the following data.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Hello pankesh</string>
```

Now, my question is - on the above webservice,  I am passing a simple data type that is  STRING.  Now, my requirement is I want to pass a complex custom object through REST request. Could you please advise me - how can I pass the custom object through a REST request on the above scenario?

The content of `web.config` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestfulWCFService.RestfulTestService">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="RestfulWCFService.IRestfulTestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you find solution. .. I am also looking same...

Answer (score 0):

1. serialize object to stream
2. pass to service as stream
3. deserialize to data contract

   [Serializing/deserializing with memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390356/c-sharp-serializing-deserializing-with-memory-stream)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But, my requirement is that I want to pass the whole object to the GET request on browser URL directly. I do not want to write a client. Here, my client interface is browser URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336807/how-to-pass-object-to-restful-service-with-get-request

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/08/08/wcf-extensibility-querystringconverter/

Comment: You need to create a custom QueryStringConverter