# AngularJs application unable to authenticate user login with Wcf Service

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf

I am consuming Wcf Service into Angular Js Application . I have one Boolean function inside the wcf service to accept the username and password. I am trying to create user login system by using Angular Js Application but when I enter the correct username and password its does not working according my expectation. There are no errors showing in Google Chrome console windows.

Here is Interface .

```
  [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "/AuthenticateUser")]
        bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin);
```

Here is Implementation ..

```
 public bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin)
        {
            // ConfigurationManager class is in System.Configuration namespace
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            // SqlConnection is in System.Data.SqlClient namespace
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //Formsauthentication is in system.web.security
                string encryptedpassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(userLogin.Password, "SHA1");

                //sqlparameter is in System.Data namespace
                SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userLogin.Username);
                SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedpassword);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int RetryAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["RetryAttempts"]);
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["AccountLocked"]))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (RetryAttempts > 0)
                    {
                        int AttemptsLeft = (4 - RetryAttempts);
                        //lblMessage.Text = "Invalid user name and/or password. " +
                        //    AttemptsLeft.ToString() + "attempt(s) left";
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Authenticated"]))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is Script code .

```
///// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  



var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])

    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {

        $scope.OperType = 1;

        //1 Mean New Entry  

        //To Clear all input controls.  
        function ClearModels() {
            $scope.OperType = 1;
            $scope.Username = "";
            $scope.Password = "";


        }


        $scope.login = function () {
            var User = {
                Username: $scope.Username,
                Password: $scope.Password,


            };
            if ($scope.OperType === 1) {

                var promisePost = myService.AuthenticateUser(User);
                promisePost.then(function (pl) {
                    $scope.Id = pl.data.Id;
                    window.location.href = "/Welcome/Index";

                    ClearModels();
                }, function (err) {
                    $scope.msg = "Password Incorrect !";
                    console.log("Some error Occured" + err);
                });
            }

        };



    }]);

app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    // Create new record  

    this.AuthenticateUser = function (User) {
        return $http.post("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/AuthenticateUser", JSON.stringify(User));
    }
})
```

Here is the HTML code..

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/RegistrationScript/LoginScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="color: red;">{{Message}}</div>
                <table style="border: solid 4px Red; padding: 2px;">

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Username</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="username" data-ng-model="Username" required="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <span>Password</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password" required data-ng-model="Password" require="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" data-ng-click="login()" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/RegistrationScript/LoginScript.js"></script>
```

Here is the screen shot when I run the application.[image: Click here to see the result]

Any Help or suggestion will he highly appreciated.

Comment: click on link displayed on console and please chk at which line u getting error in ur script!

Comment: Console does not display any error

Comment: in login you write myService.get(user) in your service i don't see any get method

Comment: Your method can't run, because you're sending an object to it

Comment: Change GET to  POST to solve your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336807/how-to-pass-object-to-restful-service-with-get-request
Check out the above subject

Comment: @Ali.Asadi sorry to say .After making changes its still same things

Comment: You must need to add ng-app tag to get your angular working here something like

    <body ng-app="WebClientModule">

Comment: Do you see the request going out in the network tab? If you hit the service with a test client like fiddler or postman does it work correctly? I think it is an issue with the scripting/markup as jitender said.

Comment: Use  `$window` for `$window.location.href`

Comment: Suggestion: Try to break the problem into simple parts then only move to integrating all in one place. By simply observing code and error, i can say there is problem in your angular app initialization. ```<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">```

Comment: Why would you ever call a Wcf service direct from a front end javascript client, gnarly, just put a facade normal http layer in front of the Wcf service,  handle translation

Answer (score 1):

I ran your example in jsfiddle to see what's going on and I changed this:

```
<body ng-app="WebClientModule">
```

I added the `ng-app` attribute and now is working properly.

See the full example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/s99t344y/2/

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialising the angular module in html side, you should add

```
data-ng-app="WebClientModule"
```